# How to checks if the given key or index exists in the array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have created an array of data from mysql database. This is how that array looks like:

```
// Fetch all the records:
while ($stmt->fetch()) {

    $output  =  "<a>\n";
    $output .=      "<h3>{$product_name}</h3>\n";
    $output .=      "<span class='price'><span class='amount'>BD.{$price}</span></span>\n";
    $output .=  "</a>\n";
    $output .=  "<div class='short_desc'>\n";
    $output .=          "$product_des\n";       
    $output .=  "</div>\n";

    //Add output to array
    $products[] = $output;      
}
```

Since I want to use this array values from outside my `while` loop and This is how I use this `$products[]` array in my page.

```
echo $products[0];
echo $products[1];
echo $products[2];
echo $products[3];
```

My question is if this `$products[]` array have one result set I can get an error.

> My error message is like this:  An error occurred in script
>   'C:\wamp\www\Computer\index.php' on line 208: Undefined offset: 2

So I tried to fix this problem using `array_key_exists()` function like this way for each echo:

```
if(!empty($products) && array_key_exists("$products[1]", $products)) echo $products[1]; else echo "No Product";
```

But still I can get error. Can anybody tell me what is wrong with this?

Thank you.

Comment: Please read the manual again, that's not how you use [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php). And we can't read for you, we can only give you the link. At the end you have to read and learn it.

Comment: @Rizier123, I read it before ask this. But I am confusing about the key of my `$products[]`. Is this `$products[1]` not the key of it?

Comment: If you are confused, do: `print_r($products);` to see the structure (keys and values) of your array, maybe this helps you to see the thing which you did wrong.

Comment: It too tried like this - `echo '<pre>', print_r($products).'</pre>';` its display [0], [1], ..... as keys

Comment: I don't get your logic. If products[1] exists echo products[5]. Who says there is a products[5]?

Comment: ^ exactly! The keys are `0`, `1`, ..., `3` So if you want to check if a key exists in your array then do it like this: `array_key_exists("1", $products)` Then you can print it without getting an error -> `echo $products[1];`

Comment: @Rizier123, I tried it. like this `if(!empty($products) && array_key_exists("[0]", $products)) echo $products[0]; else echo "No Product";` Then my values is not display. But `$products[0]' have a value

Comment: @user3733831 The keys are the numbers without the brackets! (Maybe you want to take a look again at the [array basics](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php))

Comment: Thank you @Rizier123. Problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
if( ! empty($products) ) {
    $ids = array(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
    foreach ( $ids as $id ) { 
      if ( ! empty($products[$id]) ) echo $products[$id];
    }
} else { 
   echo "No Product";
}
```

Comment: With my html I can not use `foreach`. Reason is I use these array values in different places in my page.

Comment: Why not? Show your HTML structure. Do you only need 0,1,2,3?

Comment: adjusted for 0-5 index

Answer (score 0):

The function `array_key_exists()` has, according to [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php), a signature of:

```
bool array_key_exists ( mixed $key , array $array )
```

That is to say: It will return `bool` (`TRUE` or `FALSE`) if the `$key` (`index`, would be `1` through `5` in your case) exists in `$array`.

Therefore, the accepted syntax for your case is:

```
array_key_exists(1, $products)
```

HOWEVER, perhaps more straight-forward would be the use of `empty()` or `isset()`, both of which will work in your situation as:

```
if (!empty($products[0])) echo $products[0];
// ...
if (!empty($products[5])) echo $products[5];
```

Or:

```
if (isset($products[0])) echo $products[0];
// ...
if (isset($products[5])) echo $products[5];
```

It would also be possible to do a loop, including HTML, and stay sane:

```
<!-- PRE-HTML -->

<?php if(!empty($products)) foreach((array) $products as $product) { ?>

    <!-- Product-Specific PRE-HTML -->

    <?php echo $product ?>

    <!-- Product-Specific POST-HTML -->

<?php } /* End for loop */ ?>

<!-- POST-HTML -->
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access a single index within your array, without getting a notice, you have to check, if the key exists.

You might use isset (http://php.net/manual/de/function.isset.php):

```
if(isset($products[0]))
{
  echo "yes, the key 0 is set within $products"; 
}
```

If you want to take all the entries, within your array, use foreach.

```
foreach($products as $product)
{
 echo $product; 
}
```